# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class BinarySearch
    {
      public static void main(String s[])
      {
      int a[] ,n ,i, c, lb=0, ub, mid, item;
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter size of array : ");
      n=in.nextInt();
      a=new int[n];
      ub=n-1;
      for(i=0; i<n ;i++)
         {
         c=i;
         System.out.println("enter"+ c++ +"th element of array :");
         a[i]=in.nextInt();
         }
      for(i=0; i<n ;i++)
         {
         c=i;
         System.out.println(c++ +"th element of array is :"+a[i]);
         }
      System.out.print("Enter item which is to be searched from array : ");
      item=in.nextInt();  
      mid=(lb+ub)/2;
      while((lb<=ub)&&(a[mid]!=item))
          {
          if(item<a[mid])
        ub=mid-1;
          else 
        lb=mid+1;
          }
       if(a[mid]==item)
        System.out.println(item+ "found at "+ mid+"th location");
        else
        System.out.println(item+ "not exist in this aaray");    
      }
    }
```

This is a program of binary search of an array
This code is giving an Exception named NoClassDefFoundError.
main method not found exception is there.
please help me out in resolving this exception

Comment: Funny.. even I thought the same, but its working in my eclipse now.. I've not declared BinarySearch as public

Answer (score 3):

- The name of file should be `BinarySearch.java`.
- You should compile using `javac BinarySearch.java`.
- Launch using `java BinarySearch`

Comment: it does's mateer on a saparate class.

Comment: You can run class without 'public' scope. So first point is not important.

Comment: @solvator, Thanks man, got confused with file naming restrictions and compilation rules. Edited according to your suggestion.

Comment: to compile using javac BinarySearch.java1 matters only when annotaion is being processed otherwise it dos't matter

Comment: Also,your class name can be anything you want, if it is not a 'PUBLIC' scope. Only 'public' class should reflect filename. ;) So also 1 point is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be the same name of the class file. like:
if your class file name is

```
BinarySearch.java
```

then the class should be named as

```
public class BinarySearch
```

Comment: It is not important, why you people are telling that it MUST be public? It can be just 'class BinarySearch' and you can run the file and it works.

Comment: what i am try to say that the class name should be the same class file name. and am not saying it's not working with out public :)

Comment: Name also is not important. For example I created file Example.java and replaced class inside with 'ExampleNew' or whatever you want, and it also works. ;)

Comment: i think its not gonna work if the class name is not the same as its class file name, so its very important.

Comment: No, because only 'public' scope classes should reflect filename, if it is not a 'public' scope, it can be anything you want and it works.

Comment: yea thats right in case u changed the class file name itself and your class wasn't public, but if u changed the class name, thats not gonna work.

Answer (score -1):

There is no package statement, where are you running your java command? It is not able to find that class.

Comment: why need to includes package if you have no package?